# Executing shell commands in Python

Tags: python, shell

I'm working in Linux/Python 3 and am creating some small scripts which consist of executing some commands inside of Python.

Example:
Pinging a server

```py
hostname= "server.com"
response= os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
if response == 0:
    print (hostname, 'is up!')
else:
    print (hostname, 'is down!')
```

Output:

```
PING server.com (10.10.200.55) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from server.com (10.10.200.55): icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=12.4 ms

--- server.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.446/15.446/15.446/0.000 ms
server.com is up!
```

This is working OK but I don´t need to print everything.
How can I get only the first line of the output?

Comment: Hey are you on linux or windows?

Comment: Hey there. I am in Linux

Comment: Which version of Python 3 are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subprocess in python3 to discard the output to devnull. Something like this

```
import subprocess

hostname= "server.com"
response= subprocess.call(["ping", "-c", "1", hostname], 
stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

if response == 0:
  print (hostname, 'is up!')
else:
  print (hostname, 'is down!')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL

Comment: `check_output` has no `stdout` [flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

Comment: I get this error: raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
ValueError: stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.

Comment: Apologies. changed it to call. Should work now.

Comment: Looks nice now. Thanks. How can I get the first line of the output for example?

Comment: youd have to set response= subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-c", "1", hostname]) then parse that response manually. You'd also have to use a try/except because if host is invalid it will throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

Answer that prints the opening response as well.  You may have to tweak the response if you don't want to handle it as a byte string and to handle valid but down hosts.

```
import subprocess

hostname= "stackoverflow.com"
try:
    response= subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-c", "1", hostname])
    print (response.split(b'\n')[0])
    print (hostname, 'is up!')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print (hostname, 'is down!')
```

Comment: Output: b'PING stackoverflow.com (151.101.193.69) 56(84) bytes of data.' Anyway to get rid of the b' and last ', from the output?

Comment: you'd have to convert the byte string to a regular string. you can try wrapping it in str() but I'm not 100% on that.